# How to convert SOAP UI Request to Webservice call request

Tags: loadrunner

I have SOAP-UI XML request and i need to generate script in LoadRunner Using Webservice Protocol.

When i add webservice call in Loadrunner the request contains XML Attributes in different format.

Is there any utility to convert SOAP-UI XML request to Loadrunner WebService call Request.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record an HTTP user using the LoadRunner proxy.  To make your life easier, record all headers and get rid of the ones you don't need.  I suggest this because often people will forget to go back and add the SOAP headers to the request and then the web service request fails.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I aware, there is no utility to convert the script from SOAP-UI to LoadRunner.

What you can do is install Fiddler and run the script from SOAP-UI and then save the session from Fiddler. Generate the LoadRunner script from Fiddler session.

Comment: Why would you use a third party proxy when the recording proxy in LR 12.x is based upon the Fiddler core?

Comment: We are not sure which version user3139146 is using. Also, to convert the scripts this is the way I know.